# EJB does not throw exception

Tags: exception, transactions, ejb

I have a stateless session bean which is annotated as container managed transaction, but I don't define transaction type. surprisingly the methods of this bean don't throw JPA exceptions. would you please explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

According to java ejb3_1 specification:

> REQUIRED is the default transaction attribute value for container managed transaction demarcation. The explicit specification of the transaction attribute is therefore not required.